# HDL Simulation Environment for Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: 16.04, xilinx

I've done some research on alternatives to Modelsim for Ubuntu 16.04, but so far my research led me to some dead ends. Specifically, I've tried both [GHDL](https://github.com/ghdl/ghdl) and [Vivado Design Suite](https://www.xilinx.com/products/design-tools/vivado.html). The former isn't up-to-date, and the latter requires government verification to install; something I prefer to avoid. I would like to know what other **[free]** options I have, or a workaround for my problems, when it comes to VHDL Simulation Software on Xenial Xerus. Thanks!

Comment: Plenty of choices https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HDL_simulators

Comment: @KnudLarsen As it turns out, I'm trying out GHDL. One tiny problem for me is this simulator compiles in a command line. There is no GUI, but I can make do with this. Maybe in the future, I can work on a GUI that implements GHDL for 16.04, but that can wait because my finals are killing me. Thanks a bunch for the recommendation!